# Possible dual $(\alpha,\beta)$ metric on Finsler space?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, finsler-geometry

Let $M$ be a 2-dimensional manifold with local coordinate system $(x^i)$ and  cotangent bundle $T^*\!M$ with induced coordinates $(x^i,y_i)$.

Define $F^*$ to be a (dual) Finsler metric on the cotangent bundle $T^*\!M{\backslash}\{y_i=0; y_2=0\}$:
$$
  F^* := \alpha\,\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^2-1}
$$
where $\alpha^2$ is a Riemannian metric:
$$
  \alpha := \sqrt{a^{ij} y_i y_j} \,\,,\quad
  a^{ij} = f(x)\, \delta^{ij}
$$
and $\beta$ is non-zero and dependent on one component of $y$ only:
$$
   \beta := b^{i} y_i
 \,\,,\quad
  b^{1} = 0 \,\,,\,\, b^{2} = f(x)
$$
and where $f$ is a smooth, non-zero function.

**Question:**  Can anyone comment on this metric and any properties of the Finsler space?   Specifically:

1. Is it appropriate to call it an $(\alpha,\beta)$ metric?
2. Does this Finsler structure belong to any particular well-studied type?

**Edit:** Following up on a criticism by @TedShifrin that, unusually, the Finsler structure is not defined on the whole projective tangent bundle (it omits $y_2=0$), three comments:

1. This Finsler structure describes a physical system in which $y_2 > 0$ always.
2. If we allow $y_2=0$, the metric can take infinite values. Opinions seem to vary as to whether this is permissible. For example: Burago et al ("A course in metric geometry") are comfortable with it.
3. Here is an example paper, albeit defining a Finsler metric on $TM$ rather than $T^*\!M$, in which their $\beta$ has $b^2 = 0$ and thus they have a similar issue if $y_1=0$:

Yajima, T., & Nagahama, H. (2015). *Finsler geometry for nonlinear path of fluids flow through inhomogeneous media.* Nonlinear Analysis: Real World Applications, 25, 1–8. http://doi.org/10.1016/j.nonrwa.2015.02.009

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $F^*$?

Comment: Not as far as I can see... what do you think is wrong?

Comment: What is $F^*(y_1,0)$?

Comment: I should have specified the slashed tangent bundle. Fixed.

Comment: Also: I should have specified that $\beta$ is non-zero. I'm mirroring the definition of a Kropina metric where $\beta$ is a non-zero differential 1-form on $M$. Fixed.

Comment: LOL, if it's fixed, why didn't you answer my original question?

Comment: just-wondering, How $\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}$ is defined? a 2-tensor divided by a 1-form??

Comment: If $\beta$ is required to be non-zero, then $F^*(y1,y2=0)$ is excluded. Am I missing something?

Comment: @C.F.G OK, my notation needs work. Let me see if I can do better. Editing...

Comment: I think that's OK and that was my question. Original definition is the same as your: By definition an $(\alpha, \beta)$-metric is: $F = \alpha\varphi(\alpha/\beta)$ where $\alpha=
\sqrt{a_{ij} (x)y^iy^j}$ is a Riemannian metric, $\beta = b_i(x)y^i$
is a 1-form and $\varphi(s)$ is a smooth function.

Comment: @ted-shifrin : I think the edits address your issues.

Comment: I've only seen a Finsler structure as defined on all of the projective tangent bundle, so I withdraw from this discussion. :)

Comment: @C.F.G : Yes, but, you are referring to the definition of an $(\alpha,\beta)$ metric on $TM{\backslash}0$, and it is on $TM{\backslash}0$ that most of the work (Randers, Kropina, etc) has been carried out. My metric is defined on $T^*M{\backslash}0$ (dual Finsler or Cartan space), and I have found scant literature on it.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Thank you for taking the time to comment.